# Is there any way to pass parameters to previous screen in react navigation without using onPress or onClick Events?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo, react-navigation

I'm doing a React Native Project.In that to change screens i use react navigation which is great.Moving Screens and Passing Parameters is usually bind to a onPress or onClick event as Navigator.navigate('Settings',params) to move from 'Home' to 'Settings' screen.Moving back from Settings to Home is automatically done when pressing back button,without the need to bind it in a Button.But the problem is i can't pass parameters from 'Settings' to 'Home' Screen on going back.How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple solutions for your problem.

One of the easiest would be to use some kind of global state (`Redux` if you're already using it, or even [`React Context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)) and set the params on the child to use it on the parent screen. Here's an example with `React Context`:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';

// ParamsContext.js
export const ParamsContext = createContext();

export const ParamsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const state = useState({});

  return (
    <ParamsContext.Provider value={state}>{children}</ParamsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useParams = () => useContext(ParamsContext);

// ParentScreen.js
const ParentScreen = () => {
  const [params] = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (params.childParam) {
      console.log('The value of child param is: ', params.childParam);
    }
  }, [params]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>This is the parent screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

// ChildScreen.js
const ChildScreen = () => {
  const [, setParams] = useParams();

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>This is the child screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Set params for parent screen"
        onPress={() => {
          setParams(previousParams => ({
            ...(previousParams || {}),
            childParam: 'value',
          }));
          navigation.goBack();
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

// App.js
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ParamsProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="ParentScreen" component={ParentScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="ChildScreen" component={ChildScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </ParamsProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Another way would be to use the [Passing params to a previous screen](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#passing-params-to-a-previous-screen) method in combination with [Overriding the back button](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons/#overriding-the-back-button) and [Custom Android back button behavior](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-android-back-button-handling/). But it would be too much hassle to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I haven't seen any kind of back params in react navigation. So, I think you have to do some workaround for this.

For example if you have one or two simple variables then you can declare states in `Home` component and pass the set state functions to the `Settings` component, then when you change the state in `Settings` component the changes will happen in `Home` component. Then you can go back to home component and use the changes as you like.

Or if you have redux then you can manage values globally in all components, so that you can dispatch from `Settings` component and use them in `Home` component.